# How much work could be got from temperature differences during a rocket's descent from low earth orbit?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, temperature, rocket-science, heat-engine

It strikes me that there is a lot of energy dissipated during a typical rocket's descent from Low Earth Orbit.

1. How could that energy be captured and used?

I wonder whether it might be possible to turn a descending  rocket into a beta-type [stirling engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_engine) by adding heat proof pipework at the bottom and a piston mechanism at the top.

[image]

*Image by YK Times at English Wikipedia, CC BY 2.5, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=3088708*

2. What temperature difference might be achieved during descent?
3. How much useful work (to retard the rocket's descent) might be derived from this difference?
4. What are the reasons for this being impractical/impossible/difficult?

Comment: You would have to apply the work to some object or system.  What did you have in mind?

Comment: @DavidWhite perhaps some kind of propeller or impeller

Answer (score 1):

The preferred answer is "as little energy as possible.". Reentery is designed with the expressed intent of minimizing heat transfer.  The cargo inside universally prefers the high temperatures to stay outside.  Such an engine would, by design, bring heat in, letting it warm the cold bath side of the Sterling engine.

As for how much energy could theoretically be harvested, that depends on the mass of the cold bath.  Sadly, increasing mass is also the antithesis of what rocket designers aim for.  Payload mass *drastically* limits our rockets.  And, of course, all energy gained from reentery had to be put there by the launch rocket.  Better to leave that fuel on the ground and burn it in a generator.

The one case you might get benefits is if you captured some very cold object that was on a near collision course with the Earth and diverted it towards a reentry.

If course, the political ramifications of this aren't simple.  Major governments frown on plans to take a near miss of an asteroid like the one that killed the dinosaurs, and make it into a hit.  Very unpopular

Comment: I wonder if cooler air could be sucked in from the wake side.

Comment: I am thinking of a feedback loop where the energy captured is used to slow the re-entry thus reducing the overall heat dissipated by the rocket during the whole re-entry

Comment: The wake side is still frustratingly hot, though not as bad as the windward.  An interesting thing you could look at would be the energy density of a Sterling engine and it's cold bath versus the energy density of a rocket which could be used to slow reenty in a more traditional manner.